# Deriving the Equation for Finding the Area of a Sphere

Tags: geometry, spheres

I have a series of questions that are all, I believe, leading up to finding the formula for finding the formula for calculating the area of a sphere (the last question of the series makes me imply that). [image]

I am not able to understand the given situation because of the way the question is phrased. I would appreciate it if anyone can guide me through this process. I understand that these questions are based on one another so if someone can help me with one, or two, of the questions then I hope to complete the rest of them.

Comment: Did you show that the disk and the ring in 259 have the same area?

Comment: No, I have not been able to make any progress with any of these questions. What do they mean by the "part of the cylinder that is outside (above) the cone"?

Comment: So $H$ is the height and $R$ is the radius. Let $H-h$ be the distance of the plane from the table. Using Pythagoras you have, for the radius of the disk, $r^2+h^2=R^2$. Can you follow me? And proceed a little?

Comment: I am somewhat understanding what you are saying. However, I don't understand where the plane and the table are located. Is the bottom rectangle the plane or the table?

Comment: The bottom rectangle is the table, the plane intersects the two objects.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to figure out the answers.